# Hibernate createSQLQuery

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 tables and I don't have any assosiations among them, but the primary key in the tables is used as a column in other two tables to retrieve data. I am new to hibernate and I haven't learned to create associations yet, but I need to query data from 3 tables and return a mapped object type. I am using a sql query to do that:

```
Query q = session.createSQLQuery("select p.projectid, p.projecttitle, p.projectdescription from projects p join accounts a on p.accountid = a. accountid join addresses ad on ad.accountid = a.accountid where ad.zipcode=" + zipcode);
```

I tried to use this line :

```
List<Projects> projects = (List<Projects>)q.List();
```

to convert them, but it didn't work.

Is there anyqay to convert the Objects (`Lang.Object`) returned by this query to the mapped Projects object? Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you seen [addEntity](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) ? It can help here perhaps...

Comment: btw, you should be easily able to model this association and handle using criteria. Projects have an account, Accounts have an address, Address has zip code.

Comment: "but it didn't work" - Did it throw an exception?  Or did it just come back as nothing?

Comment: In order use addEntity, do I need to have associations?

Comment: It throws an exception, Ljava.lang.object; cannot be cast to Package.Projects.

Comment: Do you get a different error if you remove the cast? (ex: "List<Projects> projects = q.List();"

Comment: I don't get error here. I get error when I try to retrive the objects from List<Projects> projects. I don't know how to access the properties of the Lang.Object. The objects are stored as Lang.Object and the properties don't have names. How do I access the properties?

Comment: addEntity did it. I was not including the package name before the class and that is why I initially thought addEntity was not working!

Answer (score 0):

```
    List projects = q.List();

    for (Iterator iterator = projects.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){

       Object[] row = (Object[]) iterator.next();
       Projects project = new Project();
       project.setName(row[0].toString());

       System.out.println("Project name: " + project.getName());         
    }
```

or you can also do

```
    List projects = q.List();

    for (Iterator iterator = projects.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();){

       Object[] row = (Object[]) iterator.next();
       Projects project = new Project(row[0].toString());
       System.out.println("Project name: " + project.getName());         
    }
```